# Roslyn: how to update multiple projects asynchronously?

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm investigating the use of the Roslyn compiler within a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) that uses the `VisualStudioWorkspace` to update existing code.

Imagine that my current solution has 12 projects.  For each of those projects I want to:

1. Add a new code file
2. Update an existing code file

I understand about the immutability of these objects and as a proof-of-concept I've written an example that makes the changes to the first project, then the second project and so on.

I then wondered whether I could make the changes to each project using an async task and, when all tasks have completed (all projects have been updated), update the solution.

To this end, I have changed my proof-of-concept and I'm at the stage where I now have 12 updated projects.  What I'm not clear on is how I merge all the changes back into my current solution so that I may then call `myWorkspace.TryApplyChanges(sln)` in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is simply adding one file and updating another in each project, then I'm not sure that doing it in parallel is going to improve things all that much. But lets say that there is a lot of calculation to determine which files should be added/updated, what their new content should be and that this can all be determined for each project independently without the results of one project affecting the calculations for another. In this situation I would suggest performing the calculations in parallel and recording the changes you would like to make, then after the calculations are completed, apply those changes in sequence.

eg.

```cs
ConcurrentBag<(DocumentId Id, CompilationUnitSyntax Content)> documentsToUpdate = new();
ConcurrentBag<(DocumentId Id, string Name, CompilationUnitSyntax Content)> documentsToAdd = new();

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    solution.Projects,
    cancellationToken,
    (project, c) =>
    {
        // perform calculations on the project and add any required changes
        // to the above ConcurrentBag<>s

        documentsToUpdate.Add((..., ...));
        documentsToAdd.Add((DocumentId.CreateNewId(project.Id), ..., ...));
    });

foreach (var record in documentsToUpdate)
{
    solution = solution.WithDocumentSyntaxRoot(record.Id, record.Content);
}

foreach (var record in documentsToAdd)
{
    solution = solution.AddDocument(record.Id, record.Name, record.Content);
}

return solution;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this should work fine. When you've done the rewrite to the first Project, you can do .Solution and that gives you a new Solution with the rewrite. Then, go and rewrite the second project in that. There's a Solution.ProjectIds collection which gives you a list of IDs that *don't* change from snapshot to snapshot.

```
var originalSolution = ...;
var rewrittenSolution = originalSolution;

foreach (var projectId in originalSolution.ProjectIds)
{
    var projectToRewrite = rewrittenSolution.GetProject(projectId);

    // update projectToRewrite here

    rewrittenSolution = projectToRewrite.Solution;
}

workspace.TryApplyChanges(rewrittenSolution);
```